# how to add Django-lfs file to the project

Tags: django, python-2.6, django-lfs

I am trying some steps given in this document "https://github.com/MrTango/django-lfs-bootstrap"

the 2nd step:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

when i am running it in **GIT** bash it's saying *pip command not found*. Anybody please help me with these commands.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is not installed on your system. If you running ubuntu you can follow this [step](http://filon.us/slava/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/). For windows, you can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).

Comment: i have installed pip from thi link "http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip" but when i run it and click on next it gives a message python 2.6 is not found in registery